# Can anyone tell me how to ask permissions for camera, location & microphone access in a react-native app using expo?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I am working on a application for which I need camera, location & microphone access permissions but I am not able to find a way to do so. Please help me with this one.

I have tried PermissionsAndroid but it returns an error to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Expo has a ton of great documentation, you should read here for all the information on their package: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/

For camera, configure your app first, follow this documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#installation

Then use `Camera.useCameraPermissions()`, documentation here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#usage

---

For microphone, configure your app with `expo-camera`, then add `microphonePermission`  to your `app.json`: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#configurable-properties

---

For location, follow this documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#installation